# Create cronjob ubuntu for user www-data using bash

Tags: bash, cron

How can I create new cronjob for user `www-data` using bash script?

This code works, but create the cronjob for `root` user (I must run this script as root)

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 1 * * * curl -L http://localhost/cronjob #my cronjob description"; } | crontab -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (required privileged user)

```
echo "0 1 * * * curl -L http://localhost/cronjob #my cronjob description" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to :

```
crontab -e -u www-data
```

For doing this you will need to be root, from the man page:

```
If the -u option is given, it specifies the name of the user whose crontab is to be used (when listing) or modified (when editing).

The  -e  option  is  used  to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables.
```

You can also add the cron to the crontabs `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

> There is one file for each user's crontab under the /var/spool/cron/crontabs directory. Users are not allowed to edit the files under that directory directly to ensure that only users allowed by the system to run periodic tasks can add them, and only syntactically correct crontabs will be written there.

In your case would be `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data`

Comment: yes it works, but I need to write new cronjob through bash script (not manually :-))

Comment: I updated the answer, you could check this as a reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0403/sysrescron-24589.html

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use linux :
Go to `/etc` directory(when you're at `root` user)

> # cd /etc

Delete both these files :

> # rm cron.deny
>
> # rm at.deny

Open cron.allow :

> # vi cron.allow

Add one line for each user allowed to use the `crontab` command to create `cron jobs`, such as:

```
john
linda
www-data
```

Finally, edit at.allow using a text editor such as `vi`, enter:

> # vi at.allow

Add one line for each user allowed to use the at command to create at jobs, again such as:

```
john
linda
www-data
```